# insufficient_scope errors with /me/activities feed

Tags: soundcloud

I am failing at retrieving my activities feed (*/me/activities*) from Soundcloud & thought someone might be able to point out what I'm doing incorrectly.

I can access the */connect* endpoint, but only if I specify a *scope* value of *non-expiring*.  Using a value of *** returns the error *invalid_scope* with an *error_description* of:

```
The requested scope is invalid, unknown or malformed.
```

I can exchange the resulting code for a token at the */oauth2/token* endpoint, but only when setting *grant_type* to *client_credentials*.

I've attempted to request */me/activities* with both GET and POST, providing *oauth_token* (and trying with and without a *limit* argument) and am being met with a 403 response * the following response header error:

```
OAuth realm="SoundCloud", error="insufficient_scope"
```

Answer (score 2):

Requesting a *grant_type* of *authorization_code* when requesting at /oauth2/token fixed the issue.